# Boostrap 3 - How to inherit height from another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns. I would like the smaller column's height to inherit the larger column's height. Ie: The left column has content to fill a height of 300px, and the right column has content to fill a height of 500px. I would like the left column to inherit the height of the right column. I've tried playing around with it several ways, including setting height: auto and height: 100% but I'm not getting my desired result. I'm using Bootstrap 3. Can you point me in the right direction?

```
 <div class='jumbotron'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='col-md-3 left-column'>
        <div class='row'>
          logo
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
            <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- end navigation -->
      <div class='row'>
        <p>Address</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Office: </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div> <!-- end left hand column -->

      <div class='col-md-9 right-column'>
        <div clas='row'>
          <div class='col-md-7'>
            <h2>About</h2>
          </div> <!-- end about-left -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
      </div> <!-- end right hand column -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end jumbotron -->


.left-column {
  border-left: 1px solid #888686;
  border-right: 1px solid #888686;
}

.right-column {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #888686;
  border-right: 1px solid #888686;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

**NOTE:** You should use `@media` queries to avoid the extra height of `.left-column` on small screens.

**Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/BdyCQdeDMT) or [Full Screen View](http://www.bootply.com/render/BdyCQdeDMT)**

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .left-column, .right-column {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
.left-column {
  border-left: 1px solid #888686;
  border-right: 1px solid #888686;
  background:red;
}
.right-column {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #888686;
  border-right: 1px solid #888686;
  height: 500px;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Vertical Centering Javascript](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)